# $p(X=E(X))=1$ then $var(X)=0$

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X$ is a random variable s.t. $p(X=E(X))=1$ then $var(X)=0$ ($E(X)$ is the expected value and $var(X)$ the variance).

Is this true? I know how to prove the reverse but I can't find an easy way to prove this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$var(X)=E((X-E(X))^2=E(X^2)-E(X)^2.$$

Since $P(X=E(X))=1$, then $P(X^2=E(X)^2)=1$, which implies that $E(X^2)=E(X)^2$ (since, you can ignore sets of probability $0$ when taking expectations). So $var(X)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the fact that 
$$
var(x) = E[\left(x-E(x)\right)^2] 
$$
Then as $x = E(x)$ almost surely, $var(x) = 0 $ almost surely analgously.

Comment: Is $var(X)=0$ everywhere or only almost surely?

Comment: var$(X)$ (if it exists) is a number not a random variable, so either var$(X)=0$ or not/

Answer (score 0):

Another way: this is clearly a discrete RV, otherwise the statement $P(X= \mathbf{E}X)=1$ is incorrect. Hence this is a degenerate RV, its full mass is on one value only, hence its variance can't be positive.

Answer (score 0):

X takes only one value EX which is constant and variance of constant is zero,for X taking other than EX value prob.is zero.